# URL Scheme for Launching BlueJeans App on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, api, video, bluejeans

I'm writing up an app for connecting people to videoconferencing options, and I want the ability to directly launch installed apps (on an iPhone/iPad) from the app.

The way to do this, is to register an app's scheme in the plist, then use that scheme in a URI.

I do that already with Google Maps and Zoom. [Here's the Zoom page on that](https://medium.com/zoom-developer-blog/zoom-url-schemes-748b95fd9205) (the scheme is "`zoomus`").

I am trying to find the same scheme for the BlueJeans app, and I'm having a devil of a time, doing that. I don't want to embed their API. I want to call an installed app.

I may be able to figure it out by looking at their API (depending on how opaque it is), but I wanted to ask here, first, in case I missed something. I did root through [their documentation site](https://support.bluejeans.com/s/), and didn't have much luck. It's a fairly balkanized site.

So far, I see only that they support installing their API, which ain't happening.

I will also be looking for the answer elsewhere, and I have opened a support case with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found it.

Completely by trial and error (BlueJeans never responded to me).

It's "bjn".